# Unable to select product name text using XPath

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

I want to find "Native Starter Pro With Backend" text using XPath. The HTML code looks like this:

```
    <tr>

   <td style="text-align:left;vertical-align:middle;border:1px  
        solid #eee;word-wrap:break-word">

      Native Starter Pro With Backend

        <br/>

      <small>type: Single License</small>

      </td>

    <td style="text-align:left;vertical-align:middle;border:1px 
          solid #eee">1</td>
```

I'm trying to select product name text. I tried this: `//tbody/tr/td[1][contains(text(),'Pro With Backend')]` but nothing has worked yet.

Comment: Please take a minute to fix the indent of your HTML and provide the code you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something simple like this?

```
//td[contains(text(),'Pro With Backend')]
```

You probably don't need the predecessor tags and I'm not sure why you specified the [1] element when you are looking for some text.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried your HTML code for finding XPath

Use this, it works for me

```
//td[contains(.,'Pro With Backend')]
```

Comment: can you post whole HTML Dom so we can get the idea